# css only works dependant on order

Tags: css, styling

I have this navigation that only appears on smartphones. For testing purpose you can see a desktop version  here: http://dknytkom.dk/forside/

I am trying to replace the anchors "menu" and "Søg" with icons using background image. But for some reason the styling rules only affects one of either. If I switch the order of the css command lines, I get to select the other.

I've tried using attributes, like a[href="..."]; I've tried using a:nth-child(...), and finally given them an id each but to no avail.

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code

Comment: As you can see from this fiddle, this is the basic mark-up: http://jsfiddle.net/Jayrocket/7WRw4/

Comment: But the code is wrapped in a number of php statements and both has  have some jquery attached as well as two stylesheets, which makes it a little complicated.

Answer (score 0):

first of all we appreciate if you post the css selector code that apply to just one of them.
second as i understand your path to the picture has problem, correct it and then tell us what was the result.

[image]

if you have problem with selector use a very specific one like these two:
for first one use : `a#menu-knap.counter`
for second  you can use `a#soege-knap.counter`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Apparently, some css comments made the trouble. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience. I remove some css comment around the statements, and yup, it worked.